# Rendered não deixa que o botão funcione

Tags: jsf

tenho o código abaixo
ele só renderiza se o contratos.aditivopdf for 1

só que com esse codigo ele não entra no metodo do actionlistener
só que se eu removo esse rendered, o actionlistener chama normal

no que estou errando?

```
<p:commandButton id="downloadAditivo"
                        icon="ui-icon-arrowthickstop-1-s" value="Download" ajax="false"
                        actionListener="#{fileUploadBean.prepDownloadAditivo}"
                        rendered="#{contratosMB.contratos.aditivopdf eq 1}"
                        >
                        <f:attribute name="codigo" value="#{contratosMB.contratos.id}" />
                        <p:fileDownload value="#{fileUploadBean.download}" />
                    </p:commandButton>
                    <p:message for="downloadAditivo" />
```

Comment: Já tentou usar o `action` ? Poste o código do Controller também.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

resolvido pessoal, estava sem scoped em cima do Managed Bean

Answer (score 0):

Perdão, não conheço muito bem a sintaxe, neste trecho do código rendered="#{contratosMB.contratos.aditivopdf eq 1}", a sintaxe "eq 1" está correta? Não deveria ser algo como "== 1"? Outra coisa, não sei sua regra de negócio, mas não seria preferível usar um atributo do tipo booleano para renderizar ou não o componente?